# Programmatically getting Certificate Details

Tags: java, certificate

I have a self-signed JAR file. I would like for it to be able to:

1. Check if it is signed;
2. Get and output the details of the certificate it was signed with.

The jar does not need to check or verify the certificate with a server.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks! :)

Comment: Hey! Welcome to StackOverflow! If you'd like to learn more about how to format your answers so that other users can easily understand and answer your questions, see the [StackOverflow Markup Guide](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`CodeSource#getCertificates()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/security/CodeSource.html#getCertificates%28%29).

```
Certificate[] certificates = YourClass.class.getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource().getCertificates();
```